# How to make Folder Properties show modified and accessed dates?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, filesystems, ntfs

On Windows XP NTFS, when I right click a file → "Properties", I can see the created, last modified, and last accessed date:

[image]

However for folders, the last modified and last accessed dates aren't shown:

[image]

How do we set Windows Explorer to show the last modified and last accessed dates for **Folder Properties**?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>When looking at your files, in Explorer, click view on the menu bar and select details.  To change the details displayed, on the View menu, click Choose Details. In the Choose Details dialog box, click to select or clear the items you want to view:  https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_fcab_view_columns.mspx?mfr=true</strike>

I did find this, NOTE: This is an example when you right click on a file or folder, click on Properties, and look at the Accessed details in the General tab.  I'm not on an XP machine and can't verify it.  The example is about 1/4 down the page:  http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/243272-last-access-timestamp-enable-disable-windows.html

Comment: This doesn't work. When I right click a folder → "Properties", it still only shows the "Created" date. Your settings only work in the Windows Explorer main window view.

Comment: Sorry, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @Pacerier See my edit

Comment: It still doesn't work. I've tried both options stated in the post.